# WCF: How to deserialize parameters of a SOAP message with different namespaces?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am new to WCF and Stackoverflow. I am trying to handle a SOAP (1.2) request from an existing client.
The message would be like:

```
<s:Body>
  <ns1:MyMethod>
    <ns1:Parameter1> A string value </ns1:Parameter1>
    <ns2:Parameter2> Another string value </ns2:Parameter2>
  </ns1:MyMethod>
</s:Body>
```

Here is my server side code:

```
[SerivceContract(Namespace = "ns1...")]
public class IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(Action="http://the action url")]
    void MyMethod(string Parameter1, string Parameter2);
}
```

I can get "Parameter1" deserialized correctly, but "Parameter2" is always null. I suppose it was because of different namespaces (ns1 vs ns2).
Any helps?

Comment: Did you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Thanks for responding. My problem is on server side.

Comment: What is the definition of ns1 and ns2?

Comment: xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512"

Comment: ns2 is different, like http://schemas.microsoft.com/...

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you may need to use a MessageContract.

Comment: Did you solve this problem in the end?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unusual to have to create a service to fit the requests a client is already sending.

This is like trying to purchase a new computer which supports the drivers for a 15 year old printer.

Solution: just buy a new printer.

The client should be consuming the service, not the other way around.

Appreciate this does not directly answer your question and may be outside the scope of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I stumbled into it when trying to find the answer to a similar question.
The reason for which the Parameter1 was deserialized and not Parameter2 is probably because both fields had no namespace definition so they inherited the namespace from their parent (MyMethod). This is also explained on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440352/wcf-xml-deserialization-is-being-very-picky-about-namespaces-and-aliases/45871292#45871292) thread.
For the current case, you would need to use the custom XmlSerializerFormat and add the ns2 namespace to the Param2:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://ns1.com")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IOpenInvoiceInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyMethod Test(MyMethod req);
}

public class MyMethod
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://ns2.com")]
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

With this setup, the following call will be deserialized as expected:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ns1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://ns2.com">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ns1:MyMethod >
        <ns1:Param1>abc</ns1:Param1>
        <ns2:Param2>cde</ns2:Param2>
    </ns1:MyMethod>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```