# WCF XML deserialization is being very picky about namespaces and aliases

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization, soap, xml-namespaces

I am writing a .net WCF SOAP service, trying to integrate with a Java client. The process is a bit unusual, because the client has specified the WSDL, and I have to create a service which can accept requests from them.

Im getting some very finicky results when we try to perform the integration. Very subtle differences (that appear to be ok to my eyes) cause the XML deserialization to fail.

This is the XML actually produced by the client, which ends up giving me null values for all the child properties of CCHNameSearchResponse for example, the InterfaceControlField which is set to "999" in the XML comes across empty)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:soapclient.cch.doj.state.wi.us">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <impl:CCHNameSearchResponse xmlns:impl="urn:soapclient.cch.doj.state.wi.us" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <InterfaceControlField>999</InterfaceControlField>
```

This one works, the only difference is the namespace alias (xmlns:impl=)  which to my eyes looks like it acceptable?

```
xmlns:urn="urn:soapclient.cch.doj.state.wi.us">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <CCHNameSearchResponse xmlns="urn:soapclient.cch.doj.state.wi.us" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <InterfaceControlField xmlns="">999</InterfaceControlField>
```

**WHY? How can I get this to accept the XML as produced?**

Comment: can you try to generate the code with svcutil using the option `/serializer:DataContractSerializer`

Comment: @rene It dumped a whole bunch of errors, and the generated code had no types defined

Warning: The optional WSDL extension element 'body' from namespace 'http://schem
as.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not handled.
XPath: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:soapclient.cch.doj.state.wi.us']
/wsdl:binding[@name='CCHSoapBinding']/wsdl:operation[@name='juvAdjNameSearchResp
onse']/wsdl:input[@name='juvAdjNameSearchResponse']

Comment: apparently I cannot use the datacontract serializer as the WSDL in question contains elements that are not compatible.

Comment: Yeah, this serialization is bit of a pain. I find my self more often then not to simply give up, define the interface with the Message class and write my own serialization/ transformation stuff of the raw body.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet, but I believe the problem is that without the alias it becomes the default namespace. But if the alias is used, it must be applied to every field that is in that namespace (the children do not inherit the namespace of their parent)

Comment: You could try to create the objects that should go in that message and then serialize them using the XmlSerializer. You can then fiddle with the [XmlRoot] [XmlNamespace] attributes among others to see what needs to be added to trick the serializer to generate the same payload. When you found the correct combi that should deserialize as well.

Comment: In this case the XML being sent to us doesn't match the WSDL, so my "fix" is ultimately just to tell the client "The XML must match your own WSDL" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that without an alias, the namespace becomes the default namespace for all child elements.

With the alias, the child elements are in the "no-namespace", and therefore are not picked up correctly in the serialization.

This is per spec, so its a problem with the side generating the XML for me.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting

So either no alias should be used (per the second example in the OP) or the alias must be used everywhere, as in the sample here

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:soapclient.cch.doj.state.wi.us">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <impl:CCHNameSearchResponse xmlns:impl="urn:soapclient.cch.doj.state.wi.us" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <impl:InterfaceControlField>999</impl:InterfaceControlField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and I solved it by adding and empty namespace to the complex types that are part of the request.

```
ServiceContract(Namespace = "www.someDomainName.com")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IExampleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResponse TestCall(ServiceRequest request);
}

[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = "www.someDomainName.com")]
public class ServiceRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember (Name="CallID",Namespace="")]
    public CallID CallId { get; set; }
}
```

And then this gets properly deserialized:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:namespaceAlias="www.someDomainName.com">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <namespaceAlias:ServiceRequest >
      <CallID>
        <TransactionUID>r4werf</TransactionUID>
        <CallUID>fdsf</CallUID>
      </CallID>
    </namespaceAlias:ServiceRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```